# Compare a given Date object to a specific time on the same day

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

My goal is to check if a specific date object is within a time frame, and then show the right button on the page as a result.

Currently, I have this:

```
ng-if="payment.TransactionDateTime <= *Six PM on the same day* && payment.TransactionDateTime >= *Six PM The Day before the payment.TransactionDateTime*"
```

What should I do to make this work? I need to check if a payment occured between 6pm the day prior to the TransactionDateTime property of payment and 6pm the same day as the TransactionDateTimeProperty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, get the transaction datetime and create scope variables to compare. I'm not sure what format you have for the TransactionDateTime but this is a basic sample code.

```
if(!payment.TransactionDateTime) {
  var transactionDay = new Date(Date.parse(payment.TransactionDateTime));
  $scope.beforeSixSameDay = transactionDay.setHours(18);
  $scope.afterSixDayBefore = new Date().setDate(transactionDay - 1).setHours(18);
}
```

On your html page,

```
<div ng-if="payment.TransactionDateTime <= beforeSixSameDay && payment.TransactionDateTime >= afterSixDayBefore"></div>
```